Is there any quick way to compute/approximate a symmetric, scale-invariant (declining color) gradient around an ellipse?
First the goal is to draw en ellipse with a (grey color) gradient like this:

With minimum at the center of the line and symmetrically declining towards the in- and outside.
Other than shown in the picture above the line/gradient width should be similar on each location:
(line/gradient width named $w_\star$ in picture)

Furthermore this line width $w_\star$ need to be invariant to scaling of the major and minor ellipse axis, ellipse rotation or ellipse translation.
It will be used inside a computer program, many points $x,y$ will be checked among many ellipses.
Applying an equation solver for each ellipse and each point $x,y$ would take too long.
It turned out computing the distance (which could be used as gradient) from a point to the nearest ellipse point is quite complicated. A general solution without plugging in axis sizes, rotation, center, line/gradient width seems to require solving a quartic equation (degree of 4). 
Some of those could be solved but results had multiple thousands operations. This would not be feasible to be computed for every point and ellipse.
Can we do quicker? 
Can we approximate the distance from an ellipse to (a) given point(s)? 
Or can we use something else except the distance? 
e.g.
A ellipse can be expressed implicit with $x,y$ fulfilling:
$$L = Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
with
\begin{align*}
  A =   a^2 \sin^2\theta + b^2 \cos^2\theta \\
  B =  2\left(b^2 - a^2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta \\
  C =   a^2 \cos^2\theta + b^2 \sin^2\theta \\
  D = -2A x_\circ   -  B y_\circ \\
  E = - B x_\circ   - 2C y_\circ \\
  F =   A x_\circ^2 +  B x_\circ y_\circ + C y_\circ^2 - a^2 b^2 
\end{align*}
Instead of $ L = 0$ nearby $x,y$ return values close to $0$. However this is not symmetric. If we allow e.g. values $-w \le L \le w$ and calculate the color gradient $1-|\frac{L}{w}|$ it will not be symmetric around $L=0$. 
Can we make it symmetric?
Or can we project a point inside the ellipse to the outside?



(Some) more things done so far.
1)
I'm looking for a solution of a general ellipse with rotation $\theta$ and center located  not at the origin. 
Like shown here this requirement can be ignored as we could also rotate the given point around the target rotation by $-\theta$ and translate it by the target center.
Given this we only need to find solutions for points with $x>0$ and $y>0$ any other can be projected to such points or are trivial.
2)
Given an ellipse as an explicit vectorial equation an inner and outer boundary can be computed
$$P(t)=C_\circ+a\cdot \vec{u} \cdot \cos t+b \cdot \vec{v} \cdot \sin t$$
$$P(t)' =  -a\cdot \vec{u} \cdot \sin t+b \cdot \vec{v} \cdot \cos t$$
Normals
$$N(t) = a\cdot \vec{v} \cdot \sin t+b \cdot \vec{u} \cdot \cos t $$
$$||N(t)|| = \sqrt{a^2\cdot  \sin^2 t+b^2 \cdot  \cos^2 t }$$
Outer boundary
$$O(t) = P(t) + h \frac{N(t)}{||N(t)||} $$
And Inner boundary
$$I(t) = P(t) - h \frac{N(t)}{||N(t)||} $$

Can we make use of this computing a distance for a given point on $(x,y)$?
Finding a general equation for the closest $t$ with parameters axis length, $\theta$, center, line width, $x$, $y$ does require solving a quatric equation again (as far as I know).
3)
As approximation of 2) we can modify the implicit equation by extending the axes by $h$
$$L_{+h} = A_{+h}x^2 + B_{+h}xy + C_{+h}y^2 + D_{+h}x + E_{+h}y + F_{+h} = 0$$
with
$$\begin{align*}
  A_{+h} =   (a+h)^2 \sin^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \cos^2\theta \\
  B_{+h} =  2\left((b+h)^2 - (a+h)^2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta \\
  C_{+h} =   (a+h)^2 \cos^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \sin^2\theta \\
  D_{+h} = -2A_{+h} x_\circ   -  B_{+h} y_\circ \\
  E_{+h} = - B_{+h} x_\circ   - 2C_{+h} y_\circ \\
  F_{+h} =   A_{+h} x_\circ^2 +  B_{+h} x_\circ y_\circ + C_{+h} y_\circ^2 - (a+h)^2 (b+h)^2 
\end{align*}$$
Same with subtracting axes by $h$ leading to $L_{-h}$
Given this we can tell if a point $(x,y)$ is inside this boundary.
But how can we calculate a symmetric color gradient with this?
Some experiments using a combination of those or their difference to $L$ only result in some non-symmetric color gradients:

Does anyone have a better idea? 
Approximation is good enough if most humans wouldn't notice any difference while looking on the picture.
Best as implicit equation which does not need compute intensive operations like $\sin$, $\cos$, $\sqrt{\cdot }$ for every point $(x,y)$.
($x,y$ will be every integer point in $[-N,N] \times [-N,N]$)

@idon'tknowwhatiamdoing something like Gaussian Blur? 'Difference of Gaussians' looks good in GIMP. Good idea. Might work out but not sure about the calculation time, discrete 2D convolution can take a while for large line/gradient width. Pixels might not be dense enough for sharp-edge Ellipse $L=0$ but $L_{\pm h = 1 pixel}$ could solve this. Actually $h$ could be $1$ to half of target line width. Only requires $\log_2$ checks like a real convolution. But only integer multiplication and addition per pixel. That's might be it! Will test it.

Analytical methods are a "cul-de-sac" in these issues (much too time consuming !). Instead, work directly at the pixel level with "Mathematical morphology" tools as advised in the first comment. It is not true that 2D convolution takes time.

@idon'tknowwhatiamdoing Computing $L$ with different $h$ is working! Thanks for the hint which leads to this.

@JeanMarie time is relative. It need to calculate million of points/pixels with hundreds of ellipses and not take longer than just a couple of seconds. Computing $L$
with different $h$ should be pretty fast. But as suggested I will ask the computergraphic stack if it can be done faster/better with filter/convolution.

@UncleBob I understand your point. Besides, do you know "Mathematical Morphology" as a set of concepts/ methods going well beyond convolution ?

@JeanMarie nope, will check it out. Clicking through the wiki pages reveals some interesting sub-topics. Some (easy) I already have used before (e.g. opening/closing) but I did not knew they are part of an own mathematical subject area. Thanks for the hint. If not for this ellipse gradient problem it may help for future problems.


With some hint from idon'tknowwhatiamdoing I got the idea we can compute $L$ with different offsets $\pm h$ from $0$ to target line width. (steps size $\le$ pixel width)
$$L_{+h} = A_{+h}x^2 + B_{+h}xy + C_{+h}y^2 + D_{+h}x + E_{+h}y + F_{+h} = 0$$
with
$$\begin{align*}
  A_{+h} =   (a+h)^2 \sin^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \cos^2\theta \\
  B_{+h} =  2\left((b+h)^2 - (a+h)^2\right) \sin\theta \cos\theta \\
  C_{+h} =   (a+h)^2 \cos^2\theta + (b+h)^2 \sin^2\theta \\
  D_{+h} = -2A_{+h} x_\circ   -  B_{+h} y_\circ \\
  E_{+h} = - B_{+h} x_\circ   - 2C_{+h} y_\circ \\
  F_{+h} =   A_{+h} x_\circ^2 +  B_{+h} x_\circ y_\circ + C_{+h} y_\circ^2 - (a+h)^2 (b+h)^2 
\end{align*}$$
For given points $(x,y)$ we can check if it is in- or outside of a certain $L_{h_i}$.
If it is inside the target width $h_t$ we check if it is inside $\frac{h_t}{2}$. If yes we check if it is inside  $\frac{h_t}{4}$. If not we check if it is inside $\frac{h_t}{2}+\frac{h_t}{4}$.
And so on.
With this we can compute the distance with the step size as unit.
(If i'm not mistaken, even for step size $\rightarrow 0$ this is not equal to the distance to the closest orthogonal of a tangent of the ellipse point. It's only a approximation)

As suggested  computer graphics stack might be better place for this.
Here a link to the question there
However if you got some better idea feel free to post it here.

Edit:
Just noticed it does not work for $a = b$.
Edit2:
It turned out there is actually a (short) analytic solution.
Described here 
(Last step from equation to implementation is missing, haven't figured it out yet)
